# Laravel duplicated queries from blade directive

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, performance

I am getting duplicated queries from using a Blade directive. I am checking a user's role, and then displaying data in a table, so the query repeats itself over and over, slowing down the app.

I have registered a Blade service provider, and in the boot method I have the following:

```
Blade::if('admin', function () {
    return auth()->check() && auth()->user()->isAdmin();
});
```

In my User model:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->hasRole('admin');
}
```

And in my views:

```
@admin
    ...
@endadmin
```

I have looked at caching the query, but I don't see a way to do it for a specific user, which is what I need in this case. Is there a standard solution for this problem?

Comment: How do you observe a list of queries? `DB::enableQueryLog()`?

Comment: I am using the Laravel Debugbar by barryvdh https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: what does `hasRole` do as that is the only thing that would actually do any work

Comment: It plucks the user's role from the roles table, and checks whether the user has a given role. That is where the query appears, but it doesn't really change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use an instance of a class like `AccessService`, which is filled with common properties like `is_admin` or `user_role`. Fill it in an http middleware and use then. Of course, better to extend it with caching.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\User;

class AccessService{

    private $user;

    private $isAdmin;


    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function setUser(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->isAdmin = $user->isAdmin();
    }


    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isAdmin(){
        return $this->isAdmin;
    }

}
```

The service is filled with a middleware `app\Http\Middleware\Access.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Services\AccessService;
use Closure;
use Auth;

class Access {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $accessService = resolve(AccessService::class);

        # current user
        $user = Auth::user();

        if($user) {
            $accessService->setUser($user);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

... which is registered in `app\Http\Middleware\Kernel.php`

```
'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Access::class, // here, right after StartSession
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
```

So you just extend your blade using `AccessService`:

```
use App\Services\AccessService;
...
Blade::if('admin', function () {
    return resolve(AccessService::class)->isAdmin();
});
```

Or you can inject the service to a blade template `@inject('accessService', 'App\Services\AccessService')` and use it like `@if($accessService->isAdmin())`

Don't forget to register service as a singleton in `AppServiceProvider.php`.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down? This was the solution I was looking for. Duplicated queries resolved - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing their role in cache in a key like `user:role:{user_id}`

If you're looking for a caching solution more efficient than the file system used by default you could use Redis.

If you have a Laracasts subscription, there is a great course on Redis: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-laravel-and-redis-through-examples

Otherwise, check out the [Redis website](https://redis.io/). Laravel has easy support for Redis which makes it a breeze to use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am going to look into this further to see how I can incorporate it into the final solution.